# compile error on boost::iostreams::copy

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iostreams

I'm trying to learn boost::iostreams by some examples. Here is one of them which can't be accepted by gcc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    boost::regex reg("a.c");    
    string str("abcdef aochijk");   
    string result;
    boost::iostreams::copy(
                boost::make_iterator_range(str),    
                boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream(    
                    boost::iostreams::regex_filter(reg,"test") |    
                    boost::iostreams::back_inserter(result))    
                );
    cout<<result<<endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the errors:

```
error:no matching function for call to 'copy(boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> > >, boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream)'

error:no type named 'type' in 'struct boost::disable_if<boost::iostreams::is_std_io<boost::iostreams::filtering_stream<boost::iostreams::output> >, void>'
```

Comment: Where did you get that example code?

Comment: @JohnZwinck From a book introducing boost. I can't compile any of it code containing boost::iostreams::copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My copy of clang fails to compile that as well, telling me that `note: candidate function [snip] not viable: expects an l-value for 2nd argument`.

That seems pretty reasonable to me, and, in fact, this compiles:

```
boost::regex reg("a.c");    
string str("abcdef aochijk");
string result;
boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream ios(    
                boost::iostreams::regex_filter(reg,"test") |    
                boost::iostreams::back_inserter(result));
boost::iostreams::copy( boost::make_iterator_range(str), ios);
```

Comment: Seen almost the same here. The problem actually was in different types of operands, stripping '&' from function definition made things work.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    boost::regex reg("a.c");    
    string str("abcdef aochijk");   
    string result;
    boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream fos(boost::iostreams::regex_filter(reg,"test") |    
                                            boost::iostreams::back_inserter(result))   ;
    boost::iostreams::copy(boost::make_iterator_range(str),fos);
    cout<<result<<endl; 
    return 0;
}
```